# Typical tolerance of transformer secondary voltage?

Tags: transformer, tolerance

I bought a transformer that said it would transform 230VAC to 34VAC (actually 2x17VAC, but it came with instructions how to connect the two secondary windings in series to get 34VAC.)

Even taking into account that my outlets give 240VAC, the measured secondary voltage of 41VAC seems excessive. This is a difference of about 20% with respect to the transformer's rating.

Is this within the normal tolerance of secondary voltages, or should I look for another supplier?

The reason this bugs me is that I was planning to use this transformer to build a power supply based on an LM317. I had planned for a rather small heat sink on the LM317 (at 34VAC, my design says that there will be just two or three extra volts to be sunk), but if I now have to sink several more volts (at 1 A max), I will need a rather larger one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically, the secondary voltage varies with loading.

Considering the real-world model of a transformer:

[image]

[ImgSrc](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Equivalent-electrical-circuit-including-an-ideal-transformer_fig1_276203851)

There's always a non-zero Rs in the secondary. This resistance is real and dissipative and is defined by the number of turns, material, and thickness of the wire. Since it's always present and non-zero, there'll always be a drop across this resistance. What you are measuring is probably the open (i.e. unloaded) secondary voltage. So, if you load the secondary, you'll observe that the measured secondary voltage will be lower due to the aforementioned drop.

Remember that the secondary voltage written on the transformer's label is the voltage when it's fully loaded. For example, assuming the transformer has a VA rating of, say, 34VA. If you connect the secondaries in series and load this combined secondary with a pure resistance of 34 Ohms then you'll measure 34Vac across the secondary.

Comment: That's a pretty convincing explanation, thanks. Actually, I should have though of this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Every transformer has a "regulation" figure in its datasheet.

Allowing 5% for the input voltage, yours is about 15% which is not uncommon for a small (< 10W) transformer.

Loaded fully, it should deliver rated voltage.

Read the datasheet and design for

- regulation under no/full load
- Line voltage tolerance
- The regulator's worst case dropout voltage at full load
- Ripple voltage as the reservoir capacitor charges and drains twice each cycle (again at full load current)
- Reference voltage and component tolerances.

"Two or three extra volts" doesn't sound like enough.

Comment: What I meant was that on 34 VAC from the transformer, the input to the 317 will be on the order of 5 volts higher than the regulated output voltage, which leaves 2-3 V headroom, taking into account the 2V minimum difference between input and output for a 317.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal.

The transformer outputs the rated output voltage under rated output load current.

Without any load, the output voltage is somewhat higher.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to complicate the question, but I'm actually regulating a +17V and -17V rail, using a 317 and 337 on the rectified output, with a centre tap. So the actual input voltages to the 317 and 337 will be way less than 40VDC.

Comment: @StephanNeuhaus Well you should have given all the details, as you simply say you want to power a LM317 with 37VAC now, which changes everything.